# Let $G$ be a group. Then verify the statements with justification:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Then verify the statements with justification:

$\bullet$ If $G$ has nontrivial centre $C$, then $G/C$ has trivial centre.

$\bullet$ If $G$ does not equal $1$, there exists a nontrivial homomorphism $h\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$.

$\bullet$ If $G$ is nonabelian, then it has a nontrivial automorphism

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I think first one is not true...need a counterexample....no idea about the rest two

Comment: In the final question, if $G$ is nonabelian, what can you say about conjugacy classes of elements?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : For i) consider the group of Quaternions which has order 8.

For ii) Let $a$ be a non trivial element of $G$ and map $1$ to $a$.

iii) prove by contradiction. If $Aut(G)$ is trivial, this means $Inn(G)  \le Aut( G)
 $ is also trivial. Deduce that G is abelion.

Comment: iii) it's useful to think about inner automorphisms...

Comment: @ah11950 there will be atleast one class which has more than one element. from this how to construct an inner automorphism? any hint?

Comment: @ah11950 now I got it.

Comment: Of course, @GA316: let $\;a\notin Z(G)\;$ (why is there such an element?), so $\;\phi_a(x):=a^{-1}ax\;$ is a non-trivial inner automorphism...

Comment: Well, even easier: there exists some element $g \in G$ such that $C_G(g) \neq G$. Let $x \in G \setminus C_G(g)$, then the automorphism given by $h \mapsto h^x = x^{-1}hx$ is nontrivial since $g^x \neq g$.

Comment: @ah11950 yes correct. nice argument.

Comment: @DonAntonio your argument sound very simple and nice.

Comment: Explain the second one please.......

Comment: How Q8 is counter example of 1. Here G/C is of order 4 must be commutative so center of G/C is the whole group....I guess 1 is also true....Can someone help with a proof?